# Python equivalent of its own file descriptor

Tags: python

Php allows one to directly request data from file descriptor of the script itself using following reference

```
php://fd/2
```

I am able to pull data in the file descriptor 2 of the script that is running

What is the equivalent method for python? My goal is to open the descriptor and read it.
We are looking to access descriptor of the python process itself and it is stored under /proc/processID/fd/2 in debian at least.

Comment: File descriptor 2 is standard error - you'd access it as `sys.stderr`, although it's normally used for output rather than input...  For a descriptor that isn't one of the standard I/O channels, there's `os.fdopen()` to open one by number.

Comment: I am reading descriptor 3 and set two as example, and it is output I am looking for. System I am working with feeds data in to descriptor 3 of the script, it is binary code, and I want to open the descriptor and begin reading bytes in chunks as long as they are sent.

Answer (score 1):

In python file descriptor can be passed as just number

```
os.fdopen(2,'r')
```